# I don't find some of the things I found in synapse before upgrade, has something changed?

Tags: synapse

I am asking this silly question because before I upgraded my OS, it worked just fine. It found all the applications, files I asked it to look for. Now it wont find like 30% of the things that it found before with the previous OS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/s/synapse/synapse_0.2.10-2ubuntu3/changelog), nothing mayor changed between raring and saucy:

> synapse (0.2.10-2ubuntu3) saucy; urgency=low
>
> - Add dependency on consolekit and upower, since we use their D-Bus APIs.
>
> -- Iain Lane   Wed, 01 May 2013 00:58:45 +0100
>
> synapse (0.2.10-2ubuntu2) raring; urgency=low
>
> - Added missing lib to link, fixing FTBFS.
>
> -- Daniel T Chen   Tue, 23 Apr 2013 12:31:31 -0400
>
> synapse (0.2.10-2ubuntu1) quantal; urgency=low
>
> - Merge from Debian unstable (LP: #965564).
> - Ubuntu remaining changes:
> - debian/control:
>
>   - Build-depends on libappindicator-dev.
>
> -- Julien Lavergne   Fri, 25 May 2012 23:16:49 +0200

Comment: well, it surely doesnt work for me the way it worked before. Thanks for the info though.